# How can I get the Int for the value selected in the array using a table view?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a table view, and when I select an item I enter a screen to where I can edit the object, and then it will bring the item back into the ViewController where the array lives. I can't seem to get the index of the selected item in the array. I would imagine I the index lives in this function as I call the segue and then send over the object for editing.

Function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditArea", sender: self)
}
```

Here is where I get the array to send over.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! addArea
    if let selectedIndexPath = areaTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        // Send over the area to update
        vc.area = areaArray[selectedIndexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Basically I just need the integer value for the object so I can save in the correct slot.

Comment: I'm not understanding - you have the index into the array at `indexPath.row`, as you have shown in the `prepare(for:sender:)` function. Why is this not what you are after?

Comment: That value isn't and integer value like i need to specify the index of the array out of the function i thought the same

Comment: `indexPath.row` is an integer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` pass `indexPath.row` to the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditArea", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

Then, you can get that value later in `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! addArea
    if let row = sender as? Int {
        vc.area = areaArray[row]
    }
}
```